# How do I tag my git repository using the GitHub Mac application?

Tags: git-tag, github-for-mac

I pretty new to GitHub and personally did not have time to learn too much command line. I prefer using the GitHub Mac app for my personal projects and I was curios if I can add tags with it.

Basically I just want to tag my projects v0.1 and so on. I'm not even sure this is the best way to do it.

Comment: The mac git UI app GitX (specifically the rowanj fork, http://rowanj.github.io/gitx/ ) supports tagging and pushing tags. It's not as pretty as GitHub app but arguably easier to use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [VonC's answer](https://superuser.com/a/308682/13669) to the [same question asked on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/308585/how-can-i-create-a-tag-with-github-for-mac):

> Both in [their announcement](https://github.com/blog/878-announcing-github-for-mac) and in the [help section](http://mac.github.com/), this (tag) doesn't seem to be available (at the time of the writing of this answer).
>
> That means GitHub for Mac doesn't manage yet the tags namespace (refs/tags), and that you need to tag manually, and then `git push --tags` to GitHub also manually.

Though that was a year ago, there's still nothing to indicate that tags are supported.  There's still no mention in the help section, [subsequent](https://github.com/blog/988-github-for-mac-1-1) [blog](https://github.com/blog/1067-github-for-mac-1-2-snow-octocat) [posts](https://github.com/blog/1102-github-for-mac-easier-updates) about it don't mention tags, nor do [the release notes](http://mac.github.com/release-notes.html) (though they only cover relatively recent versions).

Comment: I don't know when they started, but the actual github.com website now supports tagging (check the Releases section on a repo page).  So, you can push your commit and then tag it on github itself.

Comment: Does it support tags yet? Couldn't find it in the client

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Github Client for Mac still doesn't handle tags.
Neither to create them or nor to retrieve them

The Github website on its side propose not only to retrieve tagged commits, but also show them as releases and propose automaticly generated zip and tar.gz bundles of the related source code.

see:

- https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-tags
- https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases
- https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software
- https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases

The good news is that tag are pulled to you local repository when doing a "sync" or a "pull" from Github Client for Mac

As @blahdiblah said, you'll have to go through command lines to manage tags locally
The "official" documentation regarding tag manipulations in command line is there:

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging

Usage is very simple:

- `git tag` list tags
- `git tag -a v1.4 -m 'my version 1.4'` create a tag with a description
- `git show v1.4` show informations about a tag
- `git push origin --tags` push last commits and the tags

Answer (score 3):

To create a tag manually via the command line:

- open Terminal and navigate to your repository (either via cd or just drag in the folder from Finder)
- use the following commands:
- git remote (displays the name of your remote, for example YourRemote)
- git tag -a v1.2 -m 'tagging Version 1.2' (creates tag v1.2 from current branch)
- git push YourRemote v1.2 (pushes the tag you've created to YourRemote)

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-tag-a-release-in-git/

Comment: did done this, but i cannot see the tag on GitHub :/

Comment: git push origin --tags

Comment: You can also just push a normal commit, then go to Github.com and "tag a release". At least that way it will show up there.